# How to make an inserted row programmatically selected in a Table?

Tags: java, vaadin

How can I make an inserted table row programmatically selected? The table is bound to `BeanContainer`and each time the add button is clicked, I would like to insert a row and make it selectable without an ItemClick.

I have seen another example for `SQLContainer` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572857/vaadin-table-selectitemid-is-not-working) but it didn't work for me.

Below is the listener of the button that inserts successfully the row:

```
addButton.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {            
    @Override
    public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) { 
        Object itemId = addList();  
        table.addItem(itemId); 
        table.getItem(itemId).getItemProperty("PS_SECTION").setValue(n);                    
        table.setValue(itemId); 
        table.select(itemId);
        table.commit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to put `table.select(itemId)` after `table.commit`?

Comment: @defaultlocale I tried it now and It didn't work. Have you got any other idea to try?

Comment: Sorry, no idea, and I don't have an environment ready. I'd try to select an item manually, check what `table.getValue()` returns and then try to emulate that. Also, try to put `setValue` after commit.

Comment: @defaultlocale No worries. Thanks anyways! I will keep trying to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Select a row programmatically]

Here is the code:

```
@Theme("mytheme")
public class MyUI extends UI {

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
    final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    layout.setMargin(true);
    layout.setSpacing(true);
    setContent(layout);

    //cache the beans
    ArrayList<MyBean> beans = getBeans();

    BeanItemContainer container = new BeanItemContainer<>(MyBean.class, beans);

    Table table = new Table();
    table.setSelectable(true);
    table.setImmediate(true);
    table.setWidth("200px");
    table.setPageLength(5);

    table.setContainerDataSource(container);

    //select programmatically
    table.select(beans.get(1));//this is the key idea! Provide the same bean from cache, for selection.

    layout.addComponent(table);
}

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "MyUIServlet", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = MyUI.class, productionMode = false)
public static class MyUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {
}

public class MyBean {

    private int id;
    private String field;

    public MyBean(int id, String field) {
        this.id = id;
        this.field = field;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getField() {
        return field;
    }

}

public ArrayList<MyBean> getBeans() {
    ArrayList<MyBean> beans = new ArrayList<>();

    MyBean bean = new MyBean(1, "Vikrant");
    beans.add(bean);

    bean = new MyBean(2, "John");
    beans.add(bean);

    bean = new MyBean(3, "Rahul");
    beans.add(bean);

    return beans;
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks! that helped me